# CKeditor automatically wraps lists

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I use CKeditor for my CMS. However, this CMS uses custom variables to display values and apply some logic. An example would be:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    [[if (val==true)]]
    <li>two<li>
    [[endif]]
    <li>three</li>
<ul>
```

However when I save this HTML source my CKeditor automatically wraps my logic in in li-tags like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>[[if (val==true)]]</li>
    <li>two<li>
    <li>[[endif]]</li>
    <li>three</li>
<ul>
```

I read the docs of course and tried a whole bunch of configs, however this auto-wrapping seems to be unable to disable. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The only thing I would think if is post-processing the content to be honest. Somehow mark "two" for a conditional and post-process the content according to the markings. CKEditor is awesome at valid html, - a text node directly inside an ul node is not really expected.

Comment: I would say there's some way to disable this automatic behaviour as a whole and let the user only add elements manually, but I guess that's not possible, too bad. Thanks for your reply anyway

Comment: Let's hope someone else thinks of a way and posts here! :)